# split array inside single quotes without using loop

Tags: php, arrays

I have array of Ids (123456,654789,395855). I will need to split it with single qoute and comma to be able to use it in mysql query. In fact I need this for IN() function.

Is there any native php function that puts all array nodes inside quotes (retrieve string ) without using any loop?

so far I come up with this. but I am looking at better way.

```
$ids = array(123456,654789,395855);
foreach ($ids as $id){
     $stringIds .= "'". $id . "',";
}

$stringIds = rtrim ($stringIds, ",");

debug($stringIds);
```

Comment: You can use `array_map`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use implode() as usual, with some extra quotes before/after:

```
$ids = array(123456,654789,395855);
$string = "'" . implode("','", $ids) . "'";
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not a native function that does this. What you have will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `implode` and `array_map` to achieve this:

```
implode(', ', array_map(function($id) { return "'$id'"; }, $ids));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_map` and `implode`  you may also look into [array_reduce](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php)

```
$ids = array(123456,654789,395855);
$quoted = array_map(function($id) { return "'$id'"; }, $ids);
$stringIds = implode(', ', $quoted);
echo $stringIds;
```

See the [ideone](http://ideone.com/3heftJ)

Answer (score 0):

You can separate an array into single quotes and comma separated list using php's implode function.

```
$array = array(123456,654789,395855);
$comma_list = "'" .implode("', '", $array) . "'";
echo $comma_list;
```

Here is reference to an article.

http://codingcyber.com/how-split-array-single-quotes-and-comma-separated-list-php-57/

Comment: Look at Maac B answer